# How to correctly implement omniauth docusign strategy for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi, omniauth

[image]I have tested my application using `JWT` and now I'm currently trying `Authorization Code Grant` implementation.
I'd like to have multiple users login into their docusign account and allow them to create envelopes.

I'm trying to implement following the code examples from [here](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-ruby)

I have overriden the docusign strategy.

Gemfile

```
gem 'docusign_esign', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.6.0'
```

lib/docusign.rb

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Docusign < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      # include OmniAuth::Strategy

      option :name, 'docusign'

      def client
        options.client_options.authorize_url = "#{options.oauth_base_uri}/oauth/auth"
        options.client_options.user_info_url = "#{options.oauth_base_uri}/oauth/userinfo"
        options.client_options.token_url = "#{options.oauth_base_uri}/oauth/token"
        unless options.allow_silent_authentication
          options.authorize_params.prompt = options.prompt
        end
        super
      end

      uid { raw_info['sub'] }

      info do
        {
          name: raw_info['name'],
          email: raw_info['email'],
          first_name: raw_info['given_name'],
          last_name: raw_info['family_name']
        }
      end

      extra do
        {
          sub: raw_info['sub'],
          account_id: @account['account_id'],
          account_name: @account['account_name'],
          base_uri: "#{@account['base_uri']}/restapi"
        }
      end

      private

      def raw_info
        @raw_info = access_token.get(options.client_options.user_info_url.to_s).parsed || {}
        fetch_account @raw_info['accounts'] unless @raw_info.nil?
        @raw_info
      end

      private

      def fetch_account(items)
        if options.target_account_id
          @account = items.select { |item| item[:account_id] == options.target_account_id }.first
        else
          @account = items.select { |item| item['is_default'] == true }.first
        end

        if @account.empty?
          raise 'Could not find account information for the user'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However the request fails everytime due to `CORS` policy although I have configured CORS in my backend application.

1. How to make this request work?
2. My rails application is running on port 4000, however app url is in port 3000.
   Therefore my redirect uri is becoming `localhost:4000/auth/docusign/callback` instead of `localhost:3000/auth/docusign/callback`.
3. Right now I'm setting client secret and client id in `application.rb` but I intend to capture client id and secret from the user, in this situation how can I pass the form values to my docusign strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [Ruby code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-ruby) from DocuSign working for OAuth Authorization Code grant?

It uses Omniauth for the Authorization Code grant.

If you don't have it working, then that would be the first step.

OAuth Authorization Code grant does not use or need CORS. Whatever piece of code on the browser is trying to make an Ajax that is running into a CORS restriction is the problem.

Regarding your other questions:

**Which port:** Whatever port your rails app is running on is the port that the redirect will need to specify. The last leg of the "Auth code dance" is to redirect to the application. So the port number must be correct.

**capture client id and secret from the user** Why are you planning to do this? Users do not have their own client ids. Perhaps you meant that an administrator who is installing your software will need to set the client id and secret. An env file is a good place for such configuration information.

Note: If you're creating a multi-tenant application then you do NOT need a separate client id for each user. A DocuSign client id can be used by **any** user who is part of **any** account on **any** DocuSign platform system, worldwide.

The client id is for the application, not for the users of the application.